# How to do casting for List<Object> to Page<Object> in ebean play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have a list object in my method and I want to convert this list object to page object and return the Page object. This is my requirement but I'm unable to do the casting. Please help me in finding a solution. Here below I have provide some sample code for my example:

```
public static Page<Employee> page2(){
    List<Employee> allIds = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Employee e=new Employee();
    allIds.add(e);
    Page<Employee> pageObject =(Page<Employee>)allIds;
}
```

Getting Below Error:

```
 [ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.avaje.ebean.Page]
```

Comment: Which version of Ebean are you using?

Comment: Also, from where is this `Page` class coming? I could not find it at Ebean source code.

Comment: I am using EBean 3.3.2 ORM framework.

Comment: `com.avaje.ebean.Page` class is really not an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`, as you can [see at the code](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/blob/avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4/src/main/java/com/avaje/ebean/Page.java). What are you trying to solve with this code? It does not makes any sense to me.